# How can I use the data from foreach in blade.php?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I am using a foreach like below and when I say var_dump from here, 3 values ​​come. I want to add these values ​​to the table from blade.php page, how can I do it?

**Controller.php**

```
$videohistories = VideoHistory::where('user_id', $id)
            ->when(!empty($begin_date), function ($query) use ($int_begin_date) {
                $query->where('begin_time', '>=', ($int_begin_date));
            })
            ->when(!empty($int_end_date), function ($query) use ($int_end_date) {
                $query->where('begin_time', '<=', $int_end_date);
            })
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc');

         //3 values ​​are coming from below foreach
        $videohistoriesss = $videohistories->get(['id', 'prop_table']);
        foreach ($videohistoriesss as $videohistory) {
            $videohistory->total_ticket = DB::table($videohistory->prop_table)->where('to_user_id', $id)->where('video_id', $videohistory->id)->sum('total_ticket');
  
        }
```

3 values ​​come with var_dump from the videohistoriess foreach

**Blade.php**

In the foreach below, different data is returning and I want to bring these 3 data in this table.

```
@foreach ($videohistories as $videohistory)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $videohistory->create_time) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $videohistory->end_time) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ diff_date_format($videohistory->begin_time, $videohistory->end_time, "%H sa %i dk. %s sn") }}</td>
                        <td>I want to return those 3 data in this part</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

[I don't want the first 3 columns in the table in blade.php to change. Only 3 values ​​are returned in the array from the foreach in the controller. I want to return this data in the 4th column of the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgT4S.png)

Comment: Have you looked at `@php`; this is definitely one workable solution.

Comment: I didn't understand, what do you call a viable solution? @AndrewHardiman

Comment: Within a Blade template you have access to the `@php` directive which will allow you to execute plain PHP within your template, you could therefore call any of PHP's date/time functions.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand the problem. I have no problem with date and time. There are 3 values ​​coming from the foreach in the controller and I say, how do I add these 3 values ​​to this table? @AndrewHardiman

Answer (score 0):

In your @foreach, you can create the new records.

```
use App\Models\VideoHistory;
 
$videoHistory = VideoHistory::create([
    'create_time' => $videohistory->create_time,
    'end_time' => $videohistory->end_time,
    'begin_time' => $videohistory->begin_time,
]);
```

Comment: I don't want the first 3 columns of the table in blade.php to change. Just from the foreach in the controller array:3 [▼
  0 => "200"
  1 => "400"
  2 => "400"
] returns values ​​like this. I want to return this data in the 4th column of the table. @KarlHill

Comment: You will have to make the full table with all data from VideoHistory Model, you can perfectly remake all table with the collection that come from `$videohistoriesss = $videohistories->get(); `. Pass that collection to the view and remake full table.  Probably yo have to convert dates from int to date format, but Carbon make this a breeze. Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($date)->format('Y-m-d G:i');